# Creating a KnockoutJS observable with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using my own simple templating system for my app and will be loading an unknown number of the 'same' templates per page.

So basically, I grab some data via an ajax call and get a uniqueId. I'm then loading a template into my page and applying ids and a data-bind="with: " using the uniqueId.

```
<div id="content-uniqueId">
    <div data-bind="with: uniqueId">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I call a function and am trying to create an observableArray using the uniqueId, so that it binds to my 'with'.

Something like:

```
function(uniqueId) {
     var theObservable = uniqueId;
     theObservable = ko.observableArray(); // make the observable name equal to uniqueId
     // get some data
     theObservable(new data);
}
```

I've created a JS Fiddle to help clear things up but it won't work because I'm not getting ajax data or passing a unique id.

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EYHuY/1/)

**EDIT:**

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYHuY/4/), per Tyrsius' suggestion below.

```
this[uniqueId] = ko.observableArray(new entityApp.dataContext.EntityModel(data));
```

Definitely one step close, but I'm getting an error:

*The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined*

But 'new entityApp.dataContext.EntityModel(data)' returns an object array, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript makes dynamic assignment and reflection simple with its object indexer:

```
var ViewModel = function(propName) {
    this[propName] = ko.observable("reflection");
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("dynamic"));
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHz4k/1/) demonstrating the binding.

Comment: Thanks, I'm one step closer now. But I'm getting an error still (see my edit above). Updated your JS Fiddle so it more closely matches what my situation is. I don't see why it's not working but I'm probably still doing something stupid. http://jsfiddle.net/FHz4k/3/

Comment: Your problem is that `theArray` is an object, not an array. Did you want `theArray.names`, or perhaps `ko.observableArray([theArray])`?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know. When I wasn't using these dynamic uniqueIds, using that data worked fine doing var obs = ko.observableArray(); then obs(new entityApp.dataContext.EntityModel(data)); I don't know. I appreciate the help. I may have to rethink my approach.

Comment: During construction it will throw an error; if you try to pass an object to an observableArray after construction, you turn it into non-array observable. What you are describing can't have worked unless your data has changed. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bQjTV/1/. Note the html

Comment: Right. Good call - that's pretty helpful. I must've messed something else up while I was switching over to the dynamic ids. I'm going back not, have it working without the dynamic ids and will start over, keeping this in mind. I'm not really sure what I did wrong but will figure it out. I don't have it worked out yet, but will mark your post as the correct answer, since it helped a lot. Thanks for having a look!